# Troubleshooting my PS1

Tags: prompt, gnome-terminal

I have a `PS1` that looks like:

```
johnsmith@someserver:~
$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n$(exitstatus)
```

Since I usually work on my laptop, having the command prompt in the next line is something I really like, hence the `\n$` by the end of the `PS1`.

Sometimes, when I navigate to previous commands using my *up*/*down* arrows, the prompt gets "corrupted" and the cursor floats at the point where the first line has the `\n` and the command recovered from history starts there, although the characters are displayed form the beginning of the line, for illustration purposes:

```
johnsmith@someserver:~
$ cp templates/template-component.yaml components/foo/my-component.yaml
```

The cursor would be blinking where the letter `e` is, the command `cp` would start there but it is displayed just as I pasted, making it very hard to know what I am editing.

What is the *cannonical* and *proper* way of doing two-line-prompt in Unix?  How could I achieve this result without my strange buggy behaviour?

Edit:

Adding more information about my setup, the shell is `bash` version `5.0.3`.  The terminal is `gnome-terminal`, version `3.30.2-2`.

Edit #2:

I have been attempting to replicate this problem in other `tty` without success, which (for me) points at `gnome-terminal` as the potential culprit here.

Comment: I just wanted to add that just being pointed to a nice resource to read about this topic would be already of great help to me.

Comment: Which version of which shell are you using, in which terminal application?

Comment: Read `man $SHELL`, the section about PROMPTS and the `PS1` variable. It is getting confused about zero-width characters you didn't mark, and prompt length

Comment: I added some more information about the type of Shell I use.  Also, read the `PROMPTING` section of `Bash` without getting much new information.  To be honest this strikes me as a `gnome-terminal` issue as I cannot replicate the bug in a `TTY`.

Comment: @waltinator, that's the usual cause for prompt problems in Bash, but is that the case here? I tried to look but I can't see unmarked escape codes or such. Or do you mean that the newline should also be marked as nonprinting?

Comment: The problem is that, sometimes, when I navigate through my command history and want to invoke a command again, but edit something (like let's say, a flag), the editing cursor is (hence, blinks and moves) in the second line (on the Y axis) but right under where it would be if I did not have the new line by the end of my PS1 (on the X axis).  The command is printed in the second line beginning right after `$ ` as I want, but it really "is starting" where my cursor is (X and Y wise), making it impossible to know what I am editing at that point.  It is hard to explain without seeing it in action.